# Is there a way to select certain elements from a separate text file in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, text-files

I have started to make an anagram solver with Python, but since I was using a lot of words (every word in the English dictionary), I didn't want them as an array in my Python file and instead had them in a separate text file called `dictionaryArray2.txt`.

I can easily import my text file and display my words on the screen using Python but I cannot find a way to select a specific element from the array rather than displaying them all.

When I do `print(dictionary[2])` it prints the second letter of the whole file rather than the second element of the array. I never get any errors. it just doesn't work.

I have tried multiple things but they all have the same output.

My code below:

```
f = open("dictionaryArray2.txt", "r")
dictionary = f.read()
f.close()

print(dictionary[2])
```

Comment: `f.read()` just gives you all of the content in the file as a string. Any index in that string gives you a character. If you want to read the lines of the file... use `.readlines()`.

Comment: Ahh, I was wondering what .readlines() did. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Have you done any research, read any guides/tutorials or the documentation? _from the array_ How do you know it's an array? You really should use a context manager to handle the file object, by the way.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277503/11301900.

Comment: @AMC I've not done a lot no, but I have had a look around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split the content of dictionaryArray2 into separate words, do:

```py
f = open("dictionaryArray2.txt", "r")
dictionary = f.read()
f.close()

print(dictionary[2])
```

If you want to split the content of dictionaryArray2 into separate lines, do:

```py
f = open("dictionaryArray2.txt", "r")
dictionary = f.readlines()
f.close()

words = dictionary.split()
print(words[2])
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I didn't realise I had to split it.

Comment: @WillLevine If this answer works for you, I will appreciate an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely it did. Thanks

Comment: @AMC I haven't looked into them too much, but I have had a quick look and they look a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, you're reading the entire file into a single long list. If your input dictionary is one word per line, I think what you want is to get a text file like this:

```
apple
bat
```

To something like this:

```
dictionary = ['apple', 'bat']
```

There's [an existing answer that might offer some useful code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list), but in brief, `f.read()` will read the *entire* file object `f`. `f.readlines()`, on the other hand, iterates over each line one at a time.

To quote from [the official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> > > If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()`.

Comment: Originally I did have it as one word per line, only I had quotes around each word as if each one was a string in the array. But this answer does clear that up. Thank you